# Why is my content appear outside?

Tags: html, css

There's a button that can be clicked to bring div '1234-variation-options' up.
I'm trying to add a title to '1234-variation-options' div, but the problem is that it also appears when the div is supposed to be 'closed'.

[CORRECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9pxA.png)
[INCORRECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IasD.png)

Here is what i have tried out:

```css
.overlay {
    /* Height & width depends on how you want to reveal the overlay (see JS below) */   
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Black fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); /* Black w/opacity */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in or slide down the overlay (height or width, depending on reveal) */
}

.overlay .closebtn {
 color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.closebtn:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.overlay-title {

}

.overlay-content {
    /*position: relative;*/
    position: absolute;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<a
  href="#1234-variation-options"
  class="variation-options button"
  onclick="document.getElementById('1234-variation-options').style.width = '100%';">
  View variations
</a>
<div id="1234-variation-options" class="overlay">
  <div
    class="overlay-title"
    style="background-color: blue; position: absolute; width: 100%;">
    <h1 style="position: relative; margin-top: 200px; color: black; background-color: yellow;">
      test test
    </h1>
    <a
      class="closebtn"
      onclick="document.getElementById('1234-variation-options').style.width = 0;">
      &times;
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm sorry if my question is unclear.
Please let me know if any other details would be helpful for you to know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you not using javascript/jQuery for this?

Comment: I understand that JS can be used for this, but my current problem is that the data is already appearing outside of where it is supposed to, even before I want it to.

Thanks for all the responses though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add

```
.overlay {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```css
.overlay {
    /* Height & width depends on how you want to reveal the overlay (see JS below) */   
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Black fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); /* Black w/opacity */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in or slide down the overlay (height or width, depending on reveal) */
    
    overflow:hidden;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
 color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.closebtn:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.overlay-title {

}

.overlay-content {
    /*position: relative;*/
    position: absolute;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<a
  href="#1234-variation-options"
  class="variation-options button"
  onclick="document.getElementById('1234-variation-options').style.width = '100%';">
  View variations
</a>
<div id="1234-variation-options" class="overlay">
  <div
    class="overlay-title"
    style="background-color: blue; position: absolute; width: 100%;">
    <h1 style="position: relative; margin-top: 200px; color: black; background-color: yellow;">
      test test
    </h1>
    <a
      class="closebtn"
      onclick="document.getElementById('1234-variation-options').style.width = 0;">
      &times;
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this style:

```
#1234-variation-options{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSS you can also use jQuery for this. With the `hide()` function you can hide it, and when the button is clicked you can make it appear. Just add this to your js file, but be sure to add a jQuery library if you don't have one already.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('h1').hide();

    $('.variation-options').click(function(){
        $('h1').fadeIn();
    });

    $('.closebtn').click(function(){
        $('h1').fadeOut();
    });

});
```

Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9Lm6s3j/)